# C# GetAllUsers() Item has already been added. Key in dictionary error

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I am new to C# using Membership to handle users.

I inherited code I didn't write.

The code is trying to get all users so it can show all in a table.  The other option it is trying to do is show each letter in the alphabet to filter by letter.
Here is the code:

```
private void Page_PreRender()
    {
        if (Alphalinks.Letter == "All")
        {
            Users.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        }
        else
        {
            Users.DataSource = Membership.FindUsersByName(Alphalinks.Letter + "%");
        }
        Users.DataBind();
    }
```

The error I am running into is on this line:

```
Users.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

When I run the page it generates the error:

*Item has already been added.  Key in dictionary: '2309'  Key being added: '2309'*.

The stack trace is:

```
   System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add) +14328157
   System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection.Add(MembershipUser user) +268
   System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords) +315
   System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers() +37
   ASP.admin_access_users_aspx.Page_PreRender() in x:\xxxxx\xxxPM\Admin\access\users.aspx:9
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +11725240
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +132
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4005]
```

I have looked on StackOverflow for a similar situation and was told it is caused by having duplicate user names... usually in a Lowercase field.

My issue is I don't know where this is coming from.  I don't have any '2309' in my users or membership tables.

My default connection in web.config is:
`<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxPM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx" />`

The following in web.config point to this **DefaultConnection**:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordFormat="Clear" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership> 
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

The SQL database in this connection has a Users table and a Membership table.  I've done queries like this for the Users and Memberships tables:

```
SELECT  COUNT(username) cnt,
      Lower(Username) as Username
  FROM [xxxxPMTest].[dbo].[Users]
  GROUP BY UserName
  HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
```

To verify I have unique users.  0 records returned.

I cannot find any duplicates.

I've tried commenting out the Users.Datasource = Membership.GetAllUsers(); and the page will load showing all of the Alphabet letters separated for filtering.  Clicking on each letter correctly filters users and none of the pages have any errors (which I would expect to find if there actually was a duplicate entry).  I can't figure out why I get this error.

What am I doing wrong?  What can I add to check if the key already exists in Membership.GetAllUsers before adding it to Users.Datasource?  Is that even the correct approach?

-- edited SQL query --

Comment: Isn't your sql query wrong?  Wouldn't you want to verify that count is > 1?

Comment: I think you have to find out what '2309' is. Probably a duplicate primary key, but that's just a guess.

Comment: You will not see a duplicate with a dictionary.  The dictionary will not allow a duplicate to be added.  It looks like the UserName table has a name and an ID.   The UserName already is in the table and you get an exception when the name already exists.  What name are you adding?  Did you check if the name is already in the table?

Comment: Does `GROUP BY LOWER(UserName)` change the behaviour?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(username) < 1` How would this _ever_ be true? How could the COUNT be 0?

Comment: DavidL and mjwills... yes I did have that incorrect however changing to greater than still showed 0 duplicates.

mjwills - I did GROUP BY LOWER(UserName) and it did not change the outcome.  Still 0 records.

Silvermind... I have been searching for 2309 everywhere in this database and I can't find anything.

Comment: jdweng - I am not trying to add anything to the list, only to show the list.  I have checked to make sure that 2309 is not in any of the tables.

Comment: you may have inserted a duplicate record in one of aspnet_users